# How to update Row_number column by not empty row in another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I have select query like that in picture. I need to update RowNum column such as it will be numerated by TIN column, like this

```
RowNum      ...     TIN                 (other columns)
1           ...     01709199810113      (other data)
            ...
            ...
2           ...     40705200210056
            ...
            ...
3           ...     02803199610090
            ...
            ...
4           ...     01007200310037
5           ...     02603200410213
6           ...     00904199310033
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to assign a row number to every row with a TIN number? If so, just run an update statement like `update T SET RowNum = RN FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever) RN FROM tblName WHERE ISNULL(TIN, '') <> '') T`... There is no need for `WHILE` loops or anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below queries,

For assigning the numbers,

```
    Update Alias SET RowNum = RN FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY Id) RN FROM YourTable WHERE ISNULL(TIN, '') <> '') Alias
```

For assigning the NULLs,

```
Update YourTable SET RowNum = NULL WHERE ISNULL(TIN, '') = ''
```

Feel free to leave a message for further questions.

Comment: I have mistake - Derived table 'Alias' is not updatable because a column of the derived table is derived or constant.

Comment: @NursultanAidarkulov does that mean... it didn't work for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table
Set row_number = tin
Where tin != ''

?
```

Comment: No, i need to numerate

Comment: You can provide some information like how it solves the above question

Comment: sorry- trying to help late at night.  didnt mean to confuse the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you need:

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT;
DECLARE @RNO INT;
DECLARE @TIN VARCHAR(50);
SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT * FROM TABLE);

WHILE(@COUNT > 0)
BEGIN

SET @TIN = (SELECT TIN FROM TABLE WHERE RowNum = @COUNT);
SET @RNO = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM TABLE WHERE RowNum < @COUNT); 

IF(@TIN <> '')
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE SET RowNum = (@RNO + 1) WHERE RowNum = @COUNT;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE SET RowNum = 0 WHERE RowNum = @COUNT;
END

SET @COUNT = @COUNT - 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help for u

```
select case when(isnull(TIN,'')='') then Null else Row_Number() over(order by TIN) end p,* from [Your_Table_Name]
where TIN is not null
union
select '' p,* from  [Your_Table_Name]
where TIN is null
```